# Can't use free space to install Ubuntu Server in a manual installation

Tags: server, partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 live in my laptop alongside Windows 8.1, but all of a sudden I'm in Filesystem setup and I want to install manually, it doesn't allow me to select free space in order to do partitions on the disk to install Ubuntu Server.

As shown in the image, my free space is 101.561Gb, but I can't set up it

[image]

Comment: I found the "new" Ubuntu Server Installer to be very buggy an unreliable. Please try the alternate server installer iso.

Comment: You have to format the free space to make partitions and then install Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: I can't give it a format specific , even I can't choose free space to do that

Comment: Did anyone find answer to this question?. i'm also stuck at the same screen. very complicated. i have already lost my windows 10 installation because of making wrong choices on this screen. Don't want to delete win10 again. please help. Free space is grayed out and not selectable for ubuntu 20.04LTS server installation.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did to fix this issue. I used Disk Management in Windows or other HDD tools to create a volume of free space. You don't have to format or assign drive letter to it. Just create a volume using any HDD tool or if you have windows already installed on this same HDD then boot to windows first and use Disk Management to create volume of this free space. Comeback to ubuntu installation and you should be able to select free space. It won't be greyed anymore. Select the free space, select format ext4 and mount '/'. Complete the installation and you should have ubuntu alongside of windows or other OS.